# Find all the points where $f$ is analytic with $f(z)= \frac{z^2+1}{(3z-1)(z-i+1)}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers, analytic-functions

I start by expanding the denominator and separating the real and imaginary but get stuck when deciding what my $u$ and $v$ should be.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid looking at real and imaginary parts.
Sum and product of analytic functions are analytic.  Quotient is analytic where the denominator is nonzero.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. One may observe that, for $a \neq0$ and for $|z|<|a|$, we have

> $$
> z \mapsto \frac{1}{a+z}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nz^n}{a^{n+1}} \tag1
> $$

and the considered function is analytic over  $|z|<|a|$.

Now, by partial a fraction decomposition, one  may obtain

> $$
> \frac{z^2+1}{(3z-1)(z-i+1)}= \frac{1}{3}-\frac{\frac{2}{5}-\frac{i}{5}}{1-i+z}+\frac{\frac{8}{45}+\frac{2i}{15}}{-1/3+z} \tag2
> $$

then one may conclude using $(1)$.